# How to "skip" div in HTML tree when using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use Flexbox on an existing site, and I need to somehow tell the browser to "skip" several divs in the tree.

Let me explain on a simplified example. I have a HTML like this

```
<body style="display: flex;   
             min-height: 100vh;   
             flex-direction: column;">
    <div id="want_to_skip">
        <div style="flex: 1;">
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and I want it to behave as it was like this

```
<body style="display: flex;   
             min-height: 100vh;   
             flex-direction: column;">
    <div style="flex: 1;">
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Unfortunately, I need the "skipped" div to be there and cannot remove it. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CSS Display L3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/) introduces [`display: contents`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-outside-contents):

> The element itself does not generate any boxes, but its children and
>   pseudo-elements still generate boxes as normal. For the purposes of
>   box generation and layout, the element must be treated as if it had
>   been replaced with its children and pseudo-elements in the document
>   tree.

```css
#want_to_skip {
    display: contents;
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}
body > div {
  flex: 1;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;   
  min-height: 100vh;   
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.top {
  flex: 1;
}
.want_to_skip {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <div class="top">   No skipping - Top   </div>
      <div class="bottom">No skipping - Bottom</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="want_to_skip">
      <div class="top">   Skipping - Top   </div>
      <div class="bottom">Skipping - Bottom</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top">   Desired - Top   </div>
      <div class="bottom">Desired - Bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, it is only supported by Firefox 37.

Comment: I tentatively accept it, even when it doesn't work. I decided not to use Flexbox at all.

Comment: Has it been implemented in any other browsers since then? Having trouble finding it in `caniuse`.

Comment: @jrochkind Not according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Browser_compatibility